# Hardy- Littlewood Circle Method

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, diophantine-approximation

I'm currently trying to get to grips with the Hardy Littlewood circle method so I'm working through Vaughan's book.

In the past I've been very bad for leaving a point behind if I don't follow it so I'm not trying to get rid of that habit by asking more questions.
For example on page 3 of his book ([see page here](https://books.google.ie/books?id=1OiULlanEzMC&pg=PA3&lpg=PA3&dq=then%20the%20function%20F%20has%20%60peaks%27%20when%20z%3D&source=bl&ots=AqLza-yI-0&sig=1GhVBC0wZCBOvM5UMgXqbCFGuZU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjb-bXEivrMAhXBuhoKHcKZAVQQ6AEIIjAA#v=onepage&q=page%203&f=false)) Vaughan tells us that for

$F(z)= \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} z^{a_m}$

if $a_m=m^2,\  \rho=1- \frac{1}{n}$, with n large and $e(\alpha)= e^{2 \pi i \alpha} $ then the function F has 'peaks' when $z= \rho e(\alpha)$ is 'close' to the point $e(a/q)$ with $q$ 'not too large'.

So (although I accept that this sounds stupid) I'm not sure about what he means by peaks, does he simply mean F has a peak or? and also why do the values of $z$ close the point $e(a/q)$ cause this?

He then goes on to tell us that F has an asymptotic expansion in the neighbourhood of such points, roughly speaking valid when $|\alpha - a/q| \leq 1/(q \sqrt{n})$ and $ q \leq \sqrt{n}$.

Here I'm not sure what he means by asymptotic expansion and why that neighbourhood is valid.

Any help with any of this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

$F$ is a complex-valued function, so you can think of "peaks" as local maxima of $|F(\rho e(\alpha))|$, where $0 < \rho < 1$ is fixed.  You can imagine that these peaks happen around certain rational values $\alpha = a/q$ ($q$ not too large) because the oscillations of $e(\alpha)$ are "in phase" with each other at rational points of the $[0,1)$ interval.  As $\rho$ gets closer to 1, the local peaks become more frequent and pronounced.

Vaughan mentions the asympotic expansion:
$$F\left(\rho e\left(\frac{a}{q}+\beta\right)\right) \sim \frac{C}{q} S(q,a)(1 - \rho(\beta))^{-1/2}$$
where $n$ is large, $\rho = 1 - 1/n$ and
$$S(q,a) = \sum_{m=1}^q e(am^2/q).$$
Vaughan says the asymptotic expansion works for denominator $q \leq \sqrt{n}$ and $\beta$ small, roughly $\beta \leq 1/(q\sqrt{n})$.  You can interpret this to mean that $F(\rho e(a/q+\beta))$ is approximately equal to $\frac{C}{q} S(q,a)(1 - \rho(\beta))^{-1/2}$ for $\rho$ close to 1 and $q, \beta$ in the ranges given, where $C$ here is actually $\sqrt{\pi}/2$.

In fact the asymptotic estimate does not seem to quite work on the full range of $q$ and $\beta$ that Vaughan gives, and I think we need to be somewhat more restrictive.  I give more explicit estimates below.  Perhaps somewhat else can give better estimates that allow the asymptotic to work for a larger range.

First, we'll need an application of partial summation.  Suppose that $f:\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is continuous and $f(x) \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$.  Then
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n) = \int_0^\infty f(x) \, dx + \int_0^\infty \{x\} f'(x) \,dx$$
where $\{x\}$ is the fractional part of $x$.  More generally, if we have a congruence condition for our summation, we have the estimate
$$\sum_{\substack{n=1\\ n \equiv m (\bmod q)}}^\infty f(n) = \frac{1}{q} \int_0^\infty f(x) \, dx - \int_0^\infty f(x) \,d\left\{\frac{x-m}{q}\right\}$$
$$= \frac{1}{q} \int_0^\infty f(x) \, dx - f(0)\left(1 - \frac{m}{q}\right) + \int_0^\infty \left\{\frac{x-m}{q}\right\} f'(x) \,dx.$$
Therefore
$$\left| \sum_{\substack{n=1\\ n \equiv m (\bmod q)}}^\infty f(n) -  \frac{1}{q} \int_0^\infty f(x) \, dx \right| \leq |f(0)| + \int_0^\infty |f'(x)| \, dx.$$

Let's apply this to the function
$$f(x) = \left(\rho e(\beta) \right)^{x^2}.$$
We have
$$\left| \sum_{\substack{n=1\\ n \equiv m (\bmod q)}}^\infty \left(\rho e(\beta) \right)^{n^2} - \frac{1}{q} \int_0^\infty \left(\rho e(\beta) \right)^{x^2} \, dx\right| \leq 1 + \int_0^\infty \left|\left(\left(\rho e(\beta) \right)^{x^2}\right)'\right| \, dx.$$
We evaluate the derivatives and integrals to get
$$\left| \sum_{\substack{n=1\\ n \equiv m (\bmod q)}}^\infty \left(\rho e(\beta) \right)^{n^2} - \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2q\sqrt{-\log{\rho e(\beta)}}}\right| \leq 1 + \int_0^\infty \left| 2x\left(\left(\rho e(\beta) \right)^{x^2}\right)(\log \rho + 2 \pi i \beta)\right| \, dx$$
$$\leq 1 + (-\log \rho + 2 \pi \beta)\int_0^\infty 2x\rho^{x^2} \, dx = 2 + \frac{2 \pi \beta}{(-\log{\rho})}.$$

Now we can estimate the full sum.  We split into residue classes to get
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\rho e(a/q + \beta) \right)^{n^2} = \sum_{m (\bmod q)} e(am^2/q) \sum_{\substack{n=1\\ n \equiv m (\bmod q)}}^\infty \left(\rho e(\beta) \right)^{n^2}.$$

Therefore we have an estimate for the full sum
$$\left|F\left(\rho e\left(\frac{a}{q}+\beta\right)\right) - \frac{\sqrt{\pi}/2}{q}  S(q,a) \frac{1}{\sqrt{-\log \rho e(\beta)}}\right| \leq \left(2 + \frac{2 \pi \beta }{(-\log \rho)}\right) q.$$

The asymptotic estimate will be with *fixed* modulus $q$ and sending $\rho \rightarrow 1^-$.  Specifically, we fix $q$ and a small $\epsilon > 0$, and put $\rho = 1 - 1/n$.  We send $n \rightarrow \infty$, so that $\rho \rightarrow 1^-$.  At the same time, for each $n$ we need to choose $\beta$ such that $\beta = O(n^{-2/3-\epsilon})$, so $\beta$ goes to zero faster than Vaughan indicated.

Note that for small $\rho$ and $\beta$, we have
$$-\log \rho e(\beta) \sim 1- \rho e(\beta)  = O\left(\frac{1}{n^{2/3+\epsilon}}\right).$$
We thereby obtain an estimate
$$F\left(\rho e\left(\frac{a}{q}+\beta\right)\right) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}/2}{q}  S(q,a) \frac{1}{\sqrt{1- \rho e(\beta)}} + O(n^{1/3 - \epsilon}).$$
Since $(1- \rho e(\beta))^{-1/2} \gg n^{1/3 + \epsilon/2} \gg n^{1/3 - \epsilon}$, we get the asymptotic
$$F\left(\rho e\left(\frac{a}{q}+\beta\right)\right) \sim \frac{\sqrt{\pi}/2}{q}  S(q,a) \frac{1}{\sqrt{1- \rho e(\beta)}}$$
as $n \rightarrow \infty$.